# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, sequential

I know this question is asked before but i was unable to get my ans out of them.

So

```
   state is [[  0.2]
     [ 10. ]
     [  1. ]
     [-10.5]
     [ 41.1]]
```

and

```
    (5, 1) # np.shape(state)
```

and when model.predict(state) it throw

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have
>   3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 1)

But....

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu',input_shape=(5,1)))
```

My first layer of model have input_shape=(5,1) which is equal to the shape of state that I am passing.

I also have 2 dense more layers after this.

---

And

```
print(model.summary()) 
// output 
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5, 5)              10        
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 5)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 5, 5)              30        
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 5)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5, 3)              18        
=================================================================
```

---

And model definition is (!!noob alert )

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu',input_shape=(5,1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things. First, the `predict` function assumes the first dimension of the input tensor is the batch size (even if you're only predicting for one sample), but the `input_shape` attribute on your first layer in the Sequential model excludes batch size, as indicated [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/). Second, the dense layers are being applied over the last dimension, which is not going to give you what you want since I assume your input vector has 5 features, but you are adding this last 1 dimension which makes your model outputs the wrong size. Try the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu', input_shape=(5,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

state = np.array([0.2, 10., 1., -10.5, 41.1])  # shape (5,)
print("Prediction:", model.predict(np.expand_dims(state, 0)))  # expand_dims adds batch dimension
```

You should see this output for model summary and also be able to see a predicted vector:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 5)                 30        
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 5)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 30        
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 5)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 18        
=================================================================
Total params: 78
Trainable params: 78
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: I added used `model.predict(np.expand_dims(state, 0))  # Input has shape (1,5,1)` and error now is. ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_4_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1)

Comment: Can you do `print(model.summary())` and update your question with the output?

Comment: I am new in deep learning so got doubts in your ans. as if we say `input_shape=(5,)` and even after that we are giving it (1,5). In your second code snippet.

Comment: Wow i dont know that thing. Updating

Comment: That's because like I said, `input_shape` excludes the batch index, but the model functions like `predict` assume you are predicting over a batch, even if you only have one sample. If `state` has shape `(5,)`, then `np.expand_dims(state, 0)` has shape `(1,5)` which means batch size of 1 and the sample has 5 features.

Comment: Okkyyyy. and i just updated my question with `model.summary()`

Comment: Can you also just write your whole model definition code? That's more helpful.

Comment: Done. I added the definition

Comment: Thankyou. i was calling .predict somewhere else also with wrong input